# How to delete a range of lines in a text file?

Tags: command-line, text-processing

I want to know how to quickly delete text with Bash. For example, I have a file named file.txt with a total of 500 lines.

I want to delete lines 80 to 146 - how do I do that?

What's is a terminal command that can do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With [`awk`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jammy/man1/awk.1plan9.html) to print in terminal:

```
awk 'NR < 80 || NR > 146' file.txt
```

Or with [`gawk`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jammy/man1/gawk.1.html) to edit file in-place:

```
gawk -i inplace 'NR < 80 || NR > 146' file.txt
```

Answer (score 6):

If this is one time I would use vi or vim

```
vi {filename}
:86,146d
:wq
```

That last one saves and quits. Using sed:

```
sed '86,146d' {file}
```

Make a backup if unsure so you can revert.